# Wordpress won't display images after transfer

Tags: wordpress

I just transferred my Wordpress site from localhost to a normal web server and images now won't show up. Those that are called by CSS are fine, but the `<img>` ones don't work. I used this code:

`UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'localhost/test/', 'www.yourlivesite.com/');`

But it didn't fix the images. Of course, I replaced the names with the correct ones.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What errors show up in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have to change couple of more options from `wp_options` table, for example these are the `home` and the `siteurl`, this can be done via PHPMyAdmin:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'http://example.com' WHERE option_name = 'siteurl';
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'http://example.com' WHERE option_name = 'home';
```

Notice, that your `wp_options` table *may* have a database prefix, in this case find the prefix in your `wp-config.php` file, under the line `$table_prefix  = '_some_prefix_';`

Успех.

Comment: I changed those too. No success. Мерси :)

Answer (score 0):

Download and install "Velvet Blues Update URLs" from the wordpress.org respitory.  In the "Old URL" field, enter the URL of the test site, and the URL of your live site in the "New URL" field. Select all options and click "Update URL's". Update your permalinks as well afterwards by just clickink "Update" in the permalink settings screen

Answer (score 0):

When transferring from local (or any dev servers) to the production environment I usually:

**1. Export the entire db as an sql file**

**2. Perform a find & replace in a text editor (and save changes...as a new filename)**

Ie: localhost/test changes to www.yourlivesite.com

**3. Import the updated version into your production db**

I prefer doing all this via phpmyadmin, if you've got access to that use it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If your database is small, download it as sql, then open it using notepad, or notepad++, then find-replace window to find `"http://localhost/your-old-path"`, replace all with `"http://yourwebsite.com"`.

dont forget to take a copy of your sql file, drop all tables from your database using phpmyadmin, then import the new sql database.

Answer (score 0):

Open up your SQL file from `phpmyadmin` into any text editor and search for

```
localhost/foldername/
```

replace with your live 'URL'. After replacing with your live URL make sure that there is no other link with `localhost/foldername/`

Hope this will help you.